# location of com.opensymphony.workflow.loader.SpringWorkflowFactory?

Tags: java, workflow, osworkflow

Does anyone know what jar contains the `com.opensymphony.workflow.loader.SpringWorkflowFactory` class file? I've already looked for it in the `osworkflow.jar`, but could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring perhaps to [com.opensymphony.workflow.spi.hibernate.SpringWorkflowFactory](http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/api/com/opensymphony/workflow/spi/hibernate/SpringWorkflowFactory.html)?

There's no com.opensymphony.workflow.loader.SpringWorkflowFactory in the [API](http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/api/)

Other reference to it (which is not in the OSWorlflow code) is in [here](http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/WF-344?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)